# Is it possible to convert any size to base64 characters?

Tags: base64

I know my question is kinda awkward but i really couldn't find the answer till now.
Is it possible to convert any video format (whatever was the size) to base 64 characters ?
Yes or No ?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Base64 is a method for encoding arbitrary binary data into text. There is nothing inherent in the format that would limit the size.